# Script to generate MD5 hash with openssl

Tags: linux, bash, openssl, passwd

I'm trying to generate some MD5 hashes with `openssl` for use with `chpasswd`

Ex. CSV file:

```
Sample,User,SU,,sauser,password
Test,User,TU,,teuser,password
User, T Test,TEST,,username,password
```

Script I created:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$(readlink -f "$1") # open csv 

while read line; do
    salt=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 1) #randomly generate 5 char salt
    user=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f5 | xargs) # cut user from csv and trim with xargs
    pass=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f6 | xargs) # cut pass from csv and trim with xargs
    echo "$user:"$(openssl passwd -1 -salt "$salt" "$pass") >> ./global_chpasswd.data # gen MD5 hash per user and store in file
done < "$file" # close csv
```

However, if I take any MD5 generated from this script and try to use it with chpasswd it does not work.

```
echo 'username:$1$K8m2T$gb3C0Sz4JlXyewe8VRhxv.' | chpasswd -e
```

This password will fail

If I try to do this without the script by hand it works:

```
echo "username:"$(openssl passwd -1 -salt salt password) | chpasswd -e
```

Comment: I believe the leading `$1$` indicates the cipher. The actual encrypted or digested password is `K8m2T$gb3C0Sz4JlXyewe8VRhxv.`. (`$` is a delimiter in the `passwd` file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV file probably has carriage returns which is being included as part of the password field (it's the final field).

Be sure to run `dos2unix` or use `tr -d '\r'` on your CSV before processing it.